# javascript cartesian product of lists

Tags: javascript, dictionary, arraylist, cartesian-product

i'd need the cartesian product of two javascript lists.

Example:

```js
let l1 = ['a','e','f'];
let l2 = ['1','3','2'];
let lp = prod(l1, l2);
```

lp would be

```
[
['a','1'],
['e','1'],
['f','1'],
['a','3'],
['e','3'],
['f','3'],
['a','2'],
['e','2'],
['f','2']
]
```

I can easily do it with for/foreach loops, but wonder if someone would have elegant suggestions with map functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use combination of reduce and map:

```
console.log(l1.reduce((result, el1) => {
  result.push(...l2.map((el2) => [el1, el2]));
  return result;
}, []));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try as following

```js
let l1 = ['a','e','f'];
let l2 = ['1','3','2'];

console.log(l1.map(a => {
  return l2.map(b => {
    return [a,b];
  })
}).flat())
```

Comment: Looks correct and elegant, but i get a "flat is not a function" error. Is flat() safe to use?

Comment: According to MDN `flat` is not available in Edge & Internet explorer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: Ok, i'd avoid it even if these are not my favorite browsers. But thanks for the answer, it's really elegant.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```js
function prod(l1, l2) {
  return l2.reduce(
    (p, b) => p.concat(l1.map(a => [a, b])),
    [],
  );
}

const l1 = ['a','e','f'];
const l2 = ['1','3','2'];
const lp = prod(l1, l2);

console.log(lp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an approach which works for more than two arrays by reducing the array and build new arrays.

```js
let l1 = ['a','e','f'],
    l2 = ['1','3','2'],
    result = [l1, l2]
        .reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```